# Going back to a list of pages after reading a page

Tags: website-design, gui-design, navigation, web-app, back-button

I'm prototyping a website which will display a list of services on a single page, in the following format.

[image: Category, and yes, I'm aware of the spelling mistakes.]

When a user clicks on the `Learn more >` link on a service, they will be taken to a page similar to the following, displaying the full information about the service.

[image: Service]

What is the most user-friendly way to allow navigation back to the `Services` page? The website will support the normal browser navigation buttons, and there aren't enough levels to justify breadcrumb navigation.

(I've got an icon to go back next to the service title in the above image, but I feel that it distracts too much from the title text. Is that unlikely to be a problem?)

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for *user friendly*, then browser's **back button** should suffice, it's a known and expected behavior, and for one level navigation, it's what most users will look for.

Now, if you want to keep context, you could use a modal window, but that will also depend on the content you have for those services and also the kind of behavior you're looking to achieve. Since a modal is disruptive, then the normal flow will be broken, which could be good if you have a CTA (which apparently you have) but could be a bit overboard for service descriptions.

Another option could be as follow: when users go down a level (eg each service page), show them a different template with a simple navigation on top or left featuring all services as well as the "back to Services" link. This way, users will be able to jump between *siblings* without friction and keeping control of their actions at every time.

Please note the different approaches above should be tested, and it's highly recommendable that your first option is based on your specific business needs. For example: if your users are likely to be interested in one and only one service between all those you have, I'd recommend a **modal or a page relying on browser's back button.**

Likewise, if you want your users to browse all your services *(which shouldn't be the case in most situations)*, then use a **secondary template with navigation, or a modal with tabs**

Answer (score 1):

You can use "breadcrumbs" which is very common and useful. It takes less space(unless you style it heavily) and users can easily navigate to various pages.

Comment: Do you know how breadcrumbs could look in this context? I think the problem is that there's only one level for them to go, e.g. `Services >> Service`.

Comment: Yeah thats an issue , what about adding a link to **service page** at the end of the clicked service page beside -> **Enquire Now** button

Answer (score 0):

Are the users going to *check out several services*?

If so going back and forth can be cumbersome.

Maybe you could use a modal window with a close window.  You could even allow the users to navigate between services with arrows or thumbnails.

*If they aren't gonna check several* I wouldn't bother with a back button,  I would rely on the menu and the browser back button.